# Replacing ^ and | sybmbols in a matrix

Tags: r, substitution

I have the following table:

```
column1  column2
1        aaa^bbb
2        aaa^bbb|ccc^ddd
```

I would like to have a output file as follows:

```
column1   column2     column3
1         aaa         bbb
2         aaa         bbb
3         ccc         ddd
```

Could you mind to let me know if there are smart way of doing this?

#### Update:

I was trying to do two things;

For ^, I want to separate the context to the column 2 and column 3.

For |, I want to separate it to the next row, but keeping the same number in column1 (the column1 is the same for row 2 and 3.  Sorry that I make a mistake here.

To rewrite, input is as follows:

```
column1  column2 
x        aaa^bbb 
y        aaa^bbb|ccc^ddd
```

Output is as follows:

```
column1   column2     column3 
x         aaa         bbb 
y         aaa         bbb 
y         ccc         ddd
```

Comment: Catherine.  I have edited your question because it was impossible to read.  For future reference, please use the SO formatting buttons when posting a question.  If you paste text, use the {} button at the top of the editing window to indicate that a certain bit of text is either code or results.  This will then display in the way you intended.

Comment: @Catherine: I have removed references to csv files, as your problem doesn't really have anything to do with them. Instead, your problem is with data.frames/matrices. To write your table to a csv file, look at `write.csv`

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to do what you are after, is just use `strsplit`. For example,

```
> x = c("aaa^bbb", "aaa^bbb|ccc^ddd")
> ## Split the vector on ^ OR |.
> ## Since ^ and | are special characters
> ## we need to escape them: \\^ and \\|
> ## Split by column.
> new_x = unlist(strsplit(x, "\\|"))
> ## Split by row
> new_x = unlist(strsplit(new_x, "\\^"))
> new_x
 [1] "aaa" "bbb" "aaa" "bbb" "ccc" "ddd"

> ## Change the vector back into a matrix
> dim(new_x) = c(2,3)
> ## Transpose to get correct shape
> t(new_x)
     [,1]  [,2] 
[1,] "aaa" "bbb"
[2,] "aaa" "bbb"
[3,] "ccc" "ddd"
```

You could probably combine the splitting step, but I don't have enough knowledge to your data format to be confident that it will always work.

Comment: Catherine's questions is so tricky to follow because she didn't format her question properly.  I have edited the question but it needs peer review before my edits will take place.  It will then become apparent that you need an additional step in your answer to split the columns, using colsplit() or similar.

Comment: @Andre: Thanks for the question edit, I was only guessing at what Catherine was after.