# R: How to split a specific column based on symbol in R?

Tags: r, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replacing ^ and | sybmbols in a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564292/replacing-and-sybmbols-in-a-matrix)

In [previous message](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5564292/429846) (Replacing ^ and | sybmbols in a matrix), the way to remove a symbol in a list wass discussed.

Here I want to replace only one column (column Drug) of a matrix.  For example:

```
Patient Hospital Drug Response
111     AAA      B+A  Good
222     CCC      B    Good
333     DDD      A+C  Bad+relapse
```

To the following formats.

```
Patient Hospital Drug1 Drug2 Response
111     AAA      B     A     Good
222     CCC      B     NA    Good
333     DDD      A     C     Bad+relapse
```

What is the way to do so with R.

Comment: Why is this different from your previous posts? We aren't here to do everything for you and the approaches in the answers to your previous post can be applied here!

Comment: Catherine, you continue to show an utterly astounding unwillingness to do even the slightest bit yourself.  As this is probably the fifth *elementary* question within a few days, you may find people here run out patience trying to help if unless you demonstrate at least a modicum of effort and understanding of at least *some* basics.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Like this:

```
df <- data.frame(drug1 = c("B+A", "B", "A+C"))
df
df$drug2 <- lapply(strsplit(as.character(df$drug1), "\\+"), "[", 2)
df$drug1 <- lapply(strsplit(as.character(df$drug1), "\\+"), "[", 1)
df
```

resulting

```
> df
  drug1 drug2
1     B     A
2     B    NA
3     A     C
>
```

Comment: This example is giving a not flat data.frame which could not be exported to csv. Anyway to fix that?

Comment: You could use `unlist`, eg. `unlist(lapply(strsplit(as.character(df$drug1), "\\+"), "[", 2))`

Comment: How could I do this if, instead of just `A+B`, I have 1000 elements separated by `+` symbol, so I want to separate them into 1000 different columns?

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to use the function `strsplit`.

```
> clm
[1] "A+B" "B"   "A+C"
> strsplit(clm, "+")
[[1]]
[1] "A" "+" "B"

[[2]]
[1] "B"

[[3]]
[1] "A" "+" "C"
```