# Manipulating a dataset by separating variables

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data set that looks similar to the image shown below. Total, it is over a 1000 observations long. I want to create a new data frame that separates the single variable into 3 variables. Each variable is separated by a "+" in each observation, so it will need to be separated by using that as a factor.

[image]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIWzF.jpg

Comment: `reshape::colsplit(colname, split = "+", names = c("name1", "name2", "name3"))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R: How to split a specific column based on symbol in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610041/r-how-to-split-a-specific-column-based-on-symbol-in-r)

Comment: If you feel your question has been answered, please "accept" your favourite answer.  This will give reputation points to both the questioner and the answerer :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

# Data frame
df <- data.frame(MovieId.Title.Genres = c("yyyy+xxxx+wwww", "zzzz+aaaa+aaaa"))

# Data frame to data table.
df <- data.table(df)

# Split column into parts.
df[, c("MovieId", "Title", "Genres") := tstrsplit(MovieId.Title.Genres, "\\+")]

# Print data table
df
```

Comment: I am using Rstudio, I am not sure if data.table is available here, but I cannot access it using library function

Comment: You can install the package from CRAN using `install.packages("data.table")`.

Comment: Got it.. but how do I apply it to the dataframe given?

Comment: @Alec Derks: I think there is a typo. It should be `strsplit(text, "\\+"), right ?

Comment: It is not a typo. I made the example more explicit.

Comment: ah, ok. sorry, didn't know about the `tstrsplit` function.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that your `movieData` object is a single column data.frame object.

If you want to split a single element from your data set, use `strsplit` using the character `+` (which R wants to see written as `"\\+"`):

```
# split the first element of movieData into a vector of strings:
strsplit(as.character(movieData[1,1]), "\\+")
```

Use `lapply` to apply this to the entire column, then massage the resulting list into a nice, usable data.frame:

```
# convert to a list of vectors:
step1 = lapply(movieData[,1], function(x) strsplit(as.character(x), "\\+"))

# step1 is a list, so make it into a data.frame:
step2 = as.data.frame(step1)

# step2 is a nice data.frame, but its names are garbage.  Fix it:
movieDataWithColumns = setNames(step2, c("MovieId", "Title", "Genres"))
```

Comment: This all makes sense except I get an error when I run it.. It tells me this when it gets to the part that begins with "step2" .....:

Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE, : arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 2, 1

Comment: Can you supply the movie data in your example?  You can usually convert R data into copy-pasteable code using `dput(movieData)`

Comment: Read the data like this, and you won't need any further manipulation: `movieData = read.delim("http://stat.slu.edu/~speegle/project1Files/movies.dat", header = TRUE, sep="+")`

Comment: But, in the interest of seeing the question through to the end, can you show me how you'd read the data, and we can figure out why `step2` from my answer doesn't quite work?

Comment: The other way you showed me makes a lot more sense based on what we have learned in class. Thank you so much.

Comment: Sure.  But we still need to convert the list from `step1` into a data frame.  Could it be because you have movieData stored as a vector, and the first item in the vector is the "MovieId.Title.Genres" header?  If yes, then go `movieData = movieData[-1]` to get rid of it.  If that fixes your problem, then please accept the answer.